# is there a way to use try catch statement when a job is superseded?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

Below is the jenkinsfile which I use, so when the job is superseded how do I avoid from going into failure post statement?

```
stage('Publish') {
                    steps {
                        script {
                        echo "-->"
                            }
                    }
                    post {
                        success {
                            echo "success"
                        }
                        failure {
                            // Email

                        }
                       aborted {
                    echo "aborted.. "
                           }
    }
```

Comment: You mean with superseded that BUILD is Success?

Comment: the superseded build get success but this build executes failure post condition which is not right I believe.

Comment: Have you tried to print currentBuild.result ?

Comment: It has to be something wrong in the previous pipeline code. I just tried your snippet in a clean pipeline and worked without invoking failure.

Comment: I have not printed the currentbuild.result .. but I am sure what is inside the failure statement is getting executed which I dont get it

Comment: As I told you, maybe is another pipeline code which is affecting because the code in your question is working properly in a new pipeline.